# How to manipulate Jenkins HTTP JSON response

Tags: javascript, json, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Is there any way to manipulate the Jenkins HTTP response (in JSON) before it is being sent to an endpoint that I configured in my job?

So, I receive the Jenkins JSON response in my endpoint like this:

```
data.build = {
   "phase": FINALIZED,
   "number": build_number,
   "name": build_name,
   "status": status
 }
```

(build is a parameter in data)

Now I want to add a couple of environment variables from Jenkins, such as 'server' and 'url-path' to this response before I send it from Jenkins.

Is there any way or a plugin that I can use to add these parameters before I send the response? Like Post Build action?

Comment: You can use the [Groovy Postbuild Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Groovy+Postbuild+Plugin) to access variables.

Comment: @JGK - Do you know how to add a new parameter which is not there already in groovy plugin?
For example, manager.build.server = test

Something like this?